# Disproving that $\sec^{-1} x>\tan^{-1} x$ for all $x\geq1$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I was just [experimenting with WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=arcsec%20x%3Earctan%20x) today and noticed that the solution of the inequality $\sec^{-1} x\tan^{-1} x$ is $x\leq1$. I tried to prove the inequality for $x\geq1$ to be false.

**My attempt:**

Let $h(x)=\sec^{-1} x-\tan^{-1} x$. We have to prove that $h(x)<0 \forall x\geq1$. Note that $h(1)=-\pi/4$.

If $h(x)$ is a decreasing function, then QED already.
If $h(x)$ is an increasing function, then we note that $\lim _{x\to\infty}h(x)=\pi/2-\pi/2=0$. Hence, QED.

Both cases above are monotonic because the functions $\sec^{-1} x$ and $\tan^{-1} x$ are themselves monotonic.

---

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Of course $h(x)$ can be *either* increasing _or_ decreasing only, but I noticed that both cases satisfy the inequality, so I was too lazy to delve into the double derivative :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You want to prove that 
>   $$\sec^{-1} x<\tan^{-1} x\;\;\;\forall x\geq1$$

To prove this, let $y=\sec^{-1}x$, $z=\tan^{-1}x$. $$x=\frac1{\cos y}=\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}\\\implies\cos z=\sin z\cos y$$
Since we are looking at $x\ge1$, this means that $\sin z\ge\cos z$, i.e. $z\in[\pi/4,\pi/2)$, and $y\in[0,\pi/2)$.

Now fix $y$. Then $$\cos z=\cos y \sin z\\\implies |\cos z|=|\cos y|\cdot|\sin z|<|\cos y|\\\implies\cos z<\cos y$$since both are positive. Since $\cos$ is decreasing on this interval, this implies that $y<z$, i.e. $$\sec^{-1}x<\tan^{-1}x$$

Answer (score 2):

> Both cases above are monotonic because the functions $\sec^{-1} x$ and $\tan^{-1} x$ are themselves monotonic.

The sum of two monotonic functions is not necessarily monotonic. Try out 
$f(x)=\sin x-x, \ g(x)=\cos x+x$ and you see that $f(x)+g(x)$ is not monotonic. Same applies to the difference of two monotonic functions.

Thus, you cannot establish the monotonicity of $h(x)=\sec^{-1} x-\tan^{-1} x$ that way in your proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, it seems like both of your examples are indeed monotonic. The points where they have first derivative zero happens to be an inflexion point.

Comment: @GaurangTandon If you want avoid this, you can construct functions like y=sin(x)+(x-k)^3, k>0... hmm and there shouldn't be such inflection points.

Comment: Yes, that's better.